What is a 3-1/4 inch 0.131 diameter ring-shank stainless steel framing nail used for in particular?
What is a 3-1/4 inch by 0.131 diameter ring-shank stainless steel framing nail used for in particular?  Can it be used to frame out a 2x4 wall using pressure-treated lumber?

That's certainly a suitable use for those nails. While we don't usually use ring-shank for wall framing, it doesn't hurt anything, and stainless steel is one solution to the chemicals in treated lumber.
3-1/4" nails are a throwback to classic 16d (sixteen penny) framing sinkers, which were that long. Most folks now use pneumatic nails shorter than 3" because nailers tend to drive them deep and they don't want them poking through doubled studs, for example. Otherwise there's no problem with that length.
.131" also relates to 16d sinkers. Many modern framing nails are .120" in diameter, if memory serves.
